# Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication for Spring Boot Application deployed in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am new to Spring Boot and CF but I have a spring boot application running which needs Kerberos Authentication to connect to HIVE. I have a keytab and I have given it the path of "src/resources..." when I run it in my local machine, and it runs without a problem! But when I migrate this to Cloud Foundry, I have given it the path of "/home/vcap/..." which should be the right path for it to grab the keytab from.
I am also running this:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", PropertiesUtils.getProperty("KRB5_ENV"));
System.setProperty("security.auth.login.config", PropertiesUtils.getProperty("JAAS_CONF"));
```

for me to authenticate with the keytab. The JAAS config file has the location of the and the principal as well. I am getting this error when I am executing the application in Cloud Foundry

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500168) Error creating login context using ticket cache: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try to add the system property `sun.security.krb5.debug=true` and that should give you more detail about what is happening. You can do that by appending `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` to the JAVA_OPTS env variable (with `cf set-env`) & restarting your app.

Comment: Thanks! I did the debug and I was actually missing the keyword java when I was setting the property for the system!